# Which statistical analysis I should I use to determine the role of specified factors in the harmone secretions?

Tags: anova, predictive-models, ancova, lme4-nlme

We investigate stress hormones in fish. Ten fish from three different species were sampled. Each individual was placed in a small glass tank and weighed with a digital scale. After 2 minutes of handling stress, blood was collected from each fish and blood corticosterone (ng/mm2) was ascertained. We want to know how species and/or weight affect hormone levels?

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a linear regression. Hormone level is the outcome, and species and weight are the predictors. The interpretation of the coefficient for weight would be: For two fish of the same species whose weights differ by 1 unit, hormone levels are expected to differ by (X) ng/mm2. The interpretation of a coefficient for species would be: For two fish of the same weight, hormone levels from a fish of species 2 is expected to differ from those a fish of species 1 by (X) ng/mm2. (Here I'm assuming species 1 is the reference category, so it does not get a coefficient of its own.) If you had more fish you could look at interactions between weight and species (i.e., does the effect of weight depend on the species), but you currently don't have enough power to detect such an interaction.

Comment: Noah thanks for your answer, I was thinking of running an ANCOVA and treat with species like a fix factor and with weight like a covariate!!